# Compiler dependency in ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, windows

I have a third party, closed source library coming as a windows dll built with visual studio 2010.
First, I planned building an extension module for that dll using e.g. SWIG.
However that's spoiled by the fact that it's build with VS 2010, whereas all python 2 distributions are built with VS 2008.

Now it seems ctypes doesn't have this limitation.
I've built a trivial dll using VS 2010 (dependency walker shows the dll is linked to `msvcr100.dll`) with a function:

```
int fnTestLib2(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

loaded it in ctypes and

```
fcn = mydll.fnTestLib2
fcn.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
fcn.restype = ctypes.c_int
print fcn(1,2)
```

correctly prints `3`.

Now, I'm somewhat confused:
Is this just because I'm lucky and because the example is trivial or is there a fundamental difference in the underlying technique of `ctypes` and an extension module?
If yes, what is it? ;)

And finally: would it be safe to implement a ctypes wrapper library for that third party dll?

**EDIT**
Upon Serge's answer I compiled my swig extension using distutils in combination with the Windows SDK.
So, now I have my extension bla.pyd and it indeed seems to work.
Though I'm wondering if the this dependency on two c runtimes is recommendable or not. Looking at it with dependency walker:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried calling some standard library functions, in particular functions that are part of the VS2010 runtime but not yet in VS2008?

Comment: As far as I can understand Windows DLL it will work fine : each module has pointers to the modules it needs, and different versions of the msvc dll do have different names. So I cannot understand where erroneous linking could happen. Even Microsoft can does nice things ... The DLL hell in old time came from the fact that different versions of a single dll had same name even if compatibility was not fully assured !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on SWIG not ctypes, but when younger I often struggled in Windows dll hell.

First your example is way too trivial. As you do not call any function from the standard library, the example could work even without `mscvr100.dll` in  the path. You should at least try to use one simple function such as `strlen` (not `lstrlen` which would be a Windows API function ...) :

```
#include <string.h>
int testfunc(char *str) {
    return strlen(str);
}
```

I could not test because I presently have no VS2013 compiler.

Next, there is a major difference between SWIG and ctypes :

- SWIG interfaces C/C++ **source** code with Python
- ctypes directly interfaces an **executable dll** with Python

As ctypes directly interfaces a dll, you should not worry with what compiler the dll was compiled, nor which other dll it uses **provided they are on the path**. It would be really different if it had to use an *static library (xxx.a)* because in that case, the library formats should be compatible. You simply have to know what calling convention is used (stdcall or cdecl) to know if you should use windll or cdll (respectively).

By the way, according to this other post on SO [How to create a DLL with SWIG from Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693047/how-to-create-a-dll-with-swig-from-visual-studio-2010), it is also possible to create an extension dll for Python with VisualStudio 2010. It is normal because from python side, the extension library is just a dll and it uses it as such, but the hard part is to have access to the Python dll from VisualStudio environment.

Comment: That other SO post makes me curious. Everything I found on the web told me that you need the same mscv runtime that python uses (namely 2008 in my case)...

Comment: I have same sources :-). The problem when you have not the same environment is that you cannot use the import libraries from Python to generate the extension dll, not the access to the dll.

Comment: You got my 100 reps :) You helped clarifying some points. FWIW: I'll nevertheless go for ctypes and a separate C library. Turns out the SWIG overhead isn't that small after all and I don't really want a "complete" interface to that lib...